# Node.js MySQL database connection - time out (ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I try to make a simple connection to an online mysql database on a node.js server. This is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'example.org',
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypassword'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Whenever I run this server I get the error:
"connect ETIMEDOUT".

I am a 100% sure my credentials are correct and I also changed the privileges of the user in phpmyadmin (I gave this user all possible privileges).

I run the server locally, I am not sure if this has anything to do with it.

My questions are: 
- Why is it timing out?
- And how can I connect to this database?

Comment: `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` in the connect callback indicates that the connection to the mysql server could not be established. Are you sure that the `host` you entered points to an ip the mysql server is listening to and that mysql ist listening to the standard port?

Comment: @t.niese At 'host' I put the URL of the webserver I host the MySQL database on. I also tried replacing the URL with an IP address but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

Seemingly, this is related to your DataBase server.

Though, you can try to extend the timeout default, by passing a longer timeout value. (Default is 10000).

Just do:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'example.org',
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypassword',
    connectTimeout: 30000
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but it still gives me the 'ETIMEDOUT'-error. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Are you able to connect to your db from the shell?

Comment: no I wasn't, I have contacted the hosting service and apparently it is not possible to connect to this webserver from an external source due to a firewall. I am going to move the database to another server. Thanks for your help!